# docker dotnet image file creation

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I am working with windows 10 machine as i want to dockerize my dotnet application when i am trying to build my application its throwing an error.

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.302\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

below one is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AppGenerator.dll"]
```

please help me out

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can fix the issue by changing from

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
```

to

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /out
COPY --from=build-env /out .
```

Otherwise, please consult the working solution below. I have the project structure like this

[image]

My docker file is

```
#Stage 1 build 
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk as builder

#Create the src in the immediate build steps
WORKDIR  /src

# Cache the result bui copying csproj in the current folder
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy the rest of your code 
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish --output /app/ --configuration Release

#stage 2 
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app .
CMD [ "dotnet", "Fantastic.dll" ]
```

And the outcome is

[image]

Comment: thank you Toan Nguyen. But now i am getting the issue at Step 7/17 : COPY AppGenerator/AppGenerator.csproj /
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder138212429\AppGenerator\AppGenerator.csproj: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: You may need to change the step COPY AppGenerator/AppGenerator.csproj / to COPY AppGenerator.csproj /

Comment: But still it is reflecting same error even though i changed the copying path to COPY AppGenerator.csproj /

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I removed docker compose file and  just included docker file